# Prove that $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $a$, and define a new sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ by $b_n= \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}$ for all n. Prove that $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $a$.

So from my understanding, if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $a$, and $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ by $b_n= \frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}$, I think I'm suppose to use the squeeze theorem here to prove, $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $a$. I understand this but don't know how to put this in proof from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $a_n$ converge to $a$, so for each $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n>N: |a_n-a|<\epsilon$.

Hence, $\forall n>N$, we have
$$|b_n-a| = \left|\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}-a \right|\le \frac{1}{2}(|a_n-a| + |a_{n+1}-a|) \le\epsilon \tag{1}$$

Because of (1), then for each $\epsilon >0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n>N: |b_n-a|<\epsilon$. By definition, $b_n$ converge to $a$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n + a_{n+1}}2 = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n + \lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}}2 = \frac{a+a}2 = a.
$$

No need for squeeze theorem here, it's a very simple argument.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

$$b_n=\frac{a_n+a_{n+1}}{2}$$
$b_n$ is the mean between $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ therefore
$$\min (a_n,a_{n+1})\le b_n\le \max( a_n,a_{n+1});\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$
as $a_n\to a$ we have  $b_n\to a$ for the squeeze theorem.

Comment: but what if $a_n >a_{n+1} $ ?

Comment: @NN2 I have edited my answer. Do you think it's OK now?